# Covariance of two images using 3x3 moving wndow

Tags: r, matrix, r-raster

I have a raster with 2 bands and I want to compute covariance in 3x3 moving window and replace the focal value with vlue of covariance. I am looking into focal function of raster package and also got some hint to use getValuesBlock with for loop. I will really appreciate if somebody point me towards solve this problem.

Comment: can you please provide a reproducible example for your code you are trying. It is not possible to help this way

Comment: @gi.rajan have you looked at `rasterCorrelation` function?

Comment: nope, I have not seen rasterCorrelation. I will see that. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I found a solution from another post-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379604/moving-window-regression

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from another post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379604/moving-window-regressio‌​n